# Get RowVersion During Plugin Execution

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2015

I'm attempting to get the RowVersion of an entity that was retrieved in a CRM Plugin.  It is always being returned as an empty string.  Is the RowVersion not actually returned when a request is from a plugin already on the server?

Comment: believe this is only currently [available online](http://www.dynamicscrmsolutions.com/blogs/tag/RowVersion/). Are you online or onprem?

Comment: @keerz Yep.  CRM 2015 Update 1.

Comment: AFAIK the row version should be available in 7.1. Could it be that the data isn't changed since update to 7.1?

Comment: That's not it @RickardN it works when I do a select remotely, but not when I do it in the context of the Plugin.

Comment: Weird, have not seen that happening. Are you using the correct SDK version? Can't think of anything else that would give this result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Talked to Matt Barbour at ExtremCrm2015 and he said this is a bug that will be resolved in CRM hotfix in the near future.

Comment: It doesn't look like it was resolved yet :(  At least for my online CRM 2015 enivronment

Comment: Agreed @zabby, I currently have my own support ticket for this issue.  Waiting to hear back Microsoft...

Comment: @zabby just got a call from Microsoft today, they're hoping to have a fix deployed by early to mid March.